# StyleLint error and warning highlighting does not work in Angular 16 in VS Code

Tags: angular, stylelint

I want to put linting for scss files using StyleLint for Angular 16, but for some reason the error highlighting and warnings don't work! The highlighting of errors and warnings in StyleLint works only with CSS. How to enable highlighting in SCSS StyleLint in Angular 16 in VS Code?

**Non-working highlight in SCSS:**
[Non-working highlight in SCSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtkd2.png)

**Working highlighting in CSS:**
[Working highlighting in CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3BV4.png)

I did everything according to the instructions in StyleLint Docs: https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started (CSS, SCSS). CSS highlighting works!

SCSS has problems with highlighting in VS Code. I even put all plugins related to SCSS: https://stylelint.io/awesome-stylelint

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak4uS.png)

VS Code config for stylelint
[config VS Code for stylelint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD9XC.png)

Extension vs code
[extension vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCpoG.png)